# Javascript closure - mouse event

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

     for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {

    as[i].onclick = function(num) {

        return function() {
          console.log(num);
    }; 

    }(i);
}
```

Which works as expected but when I add `num` to return function as shown below. It prints out `mouse event`. Why?

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

     for ( var i = as.length; i--; ) {

    as[i].onclick = function(num) {

        return function(num) {  //Adding num here causes issue
          console.log(num);
    }; 

    }(i);
}
```

Comment: Because the event gets passed to the event handler when the event occurs. See: [DOM_Event_interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#DOM_Event_interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a function to the `onclick` event.  That function is what's called when your event is triggered.

When JavaScript calls your event function, it passes the `Event` object to it.

When you add `num` to where you say `//Adding num here causes issue`, you are creating a new local `num` variable that shadows the outer one (the value of `i`).

```
as[i].onclick = function(num) {
    return function(e){
      console.log(e, num);
    }; 
}(i);
```

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks.  I tried my best to explain it.  `Shadows` is a better word. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Because you're basically assigning something like:

```
function(num) {
    console.log(num);
};
```

to each click event. But when a function is assigned to an event, then the first argument that the function accepts is populated by the event object corresponding to the event. Therefore, when the browser looks up `num` for `console.log(num);` it starts at the innermost scope - that of the function assigned as event handler - and finds that `num` points to the event object for the click event, and hence this is what the console displays.